# Xamarin.Forms.Portable : How to display data that comes from 2 different Entities?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day everyone. I'm currently creating a simple Xamarin.Forms Portable mobile application that allows me to input record of an Employee Name and Employee Department.

I was able to retrieve the employee records created from the ASP.NET Web application Database, and display it on a ListView in the UWP part of my program. However, the data being retrieved is just coming from a single Entity namely 'Employee'. How will I display records that comes from 2 different Entities?

I have tried it using this codes but wasn't able to do so. If you need to see more codes, just please let me know. Thanks a lot.

**EmployeeController**

```
    private EmployeesContext db = new EmployeesContext();

    public IQueryable<EmployeeVM> GetEmployees()
    {
      return from emp in db.Employees
             join dept in db.Departments
           on emp.Department_id equals dept.Id
          select new EmployeeVM
           {
                Id = emp.Id,
                Name = emp.Name,
                 Department_id = emp.Department_id,
                 Department_Name = dept.Department_Name
              };


    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
  public class EmployeeVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //public string Department { get; set; }
    public int Department_id { get; set; }

    public string Department_Name { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeesContext**

```
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<XamarinFormsDemo.Models.Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<XamarinFormsDemo.Models.Department> Departments { get; set; }
```

Comment: The approach you're using is generally correct - an SQL statement with a join will pull data from multiple tables into one result set.  However, you haven't actually told us what specific problem you're having with the code you wrote, so it's difficult to say what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: @Jason my problem is that whenever I add a new Entity, it displays this error: http://prnt.sc/bogk52

Comment: this appears to be a problem with your EF data model

Comment: @Jason Ohhh. What do you think is wrong with my EF data model Sir? I've checked it right now and it's version 6.1.3. What should I do?

Comment: I have no idea, but the error message clearly says "the model has changed since the db was created".  So it sounds like your model and the db are not in sync.  Read up on EF migrations.  This has nothing to do with Xamarin.

Comment: @Jason I'm really having a hard time doing this now. Don't know what's the cause of this.