# Xamarin Forms: How to create multiple entities in one database Context?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day everyone. I'm currently creating a simple Xamarin.Forms Portable mobile application that allows me to input record of an Employee Name and DepartmentId.

Using only one Entity at first, all is running pretty smooth when I'm retrieving the created employee records from the ASP.NET Web application Database, it properly displays the records on a ListView in the UWP part of my program.

But when I add another Entity namely 'Department', the program started to display this error :  prnt.sc/bogk52

I have tried it using this codes but wasn't able to do so. If you need to see more codes, just please let me know. Thanks a lot.

EmployeeController

```
private EmployeesContext db = new EmployeesContext();

public IQueryable<EmployeeVM> GetEmployees()
{
  return from emp in db.Employees
         join dept in db.Departments
       on emp.Department_id equals dept.Id
      select new EmployeeVM
       {
            Id = emp.Id,
            Name = emp.Name,
             Department_id = emp.Department_id,
             Department_Name = dept.Department_Name
          };


}
```

ViewModel

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

//public string Department { get; set; }
public int Department_id { get; set; }

public string Department_Name { get; set; }
}
```

EmployeesContext

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<XamarinFormsDemo.Models.Employee> Employees { get; set; }

public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<XamarinFormsDemo.Models.Department> Departments { get; set; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms.Portable : How to display data that comes from 2 different Entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158014/xamarin-forms-portable-how-to-display-data-that-comes-from-2-different-entitie)

Comment: The reason was shown in InnerException in your screenshot. You may need to learn a little bit of Code first migration. I don't believe this belongs to Xamarin.Forms problem.

Comment: @Bonelol sorry Sir. I've included Xamarin.Forms because I'm currently creating one.

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista generally speaking, its because of there is mismatch between the context you defined and database. see this and update your database, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj591621.aspx